# What does `git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>` when `<tree-ish>` is not given do?

Tags: git

The manpage of `git checkout` says

> ```
> git checkout [<tree-ish>] [--] <pathspec>…
> ```
>
> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents in
>   the index or in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit). **When a
>   `<tree-ish>` is given**, the paths that match the  are updated
>   both in the index and in the working tree.

What will happen if a `<tree-ish>` is not given? Does `<tree-ish>` default to `HEAD`?

I have a file in a repository:

```
$ git status
On branch abcd
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ cat branchfile 
feature2
hello
```

I modify the file:

```
$ echo abcd > branchfile 
$ cat branchfile 
abcd    
$ git add branchfile
```

Why does `git checkout -- branchfile` not overwrite the modified file:

```
$ git checkout -- branchfile
$ cat branchfile 
abcd
$ git status
On branch abcd
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   branchfile
```

whereas `git checkout HEAD -- branchfile` does?

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- branchfile
$ cat branchfile 
feature2
hello
$ git status
On branch abcd
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, We check the defination of **index**

> The "index" holds a snapshot of the content of the working tree, and
>   it is this snapshot that is taken as the contents of the next commit.

When you use `git add`, the **index** will be updated

Back to your question,
The manpage said

> Overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents **in
>   the index** or **in the `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit)**

So, when you do

```
git checkout -- branchfile # or: git checkout branchfile
```

branchfile will be restored to the **index** (last time you added it)

And if you add `<tree-ish>` like this

```
git checkout HEAD -- branchfile
```

It will be restored to the commit **HEAD** (your last commit)

Answer (score 2):

No.  As the manpage says, it "overwrite paths in the working tree by replacing with the contents **in the index** or in the <tree-ish>".  (Emphasis mine.)

So it uses the index contents.  These will be the same as HEAD if (and only if) you don't have staged changes for that file.  Otherwise, it will be the staged changes.

Thus, when you've modified (and added the file), `git checkout --` will check out *the staged changes*.